# how to store xls report in public folder from sidekiq background jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to store xls report in public folder from sidekiq background jobs? right now its not saving the report in public folder , in views _report.xls.builder file from that file its getting data from controller and downloading.

Answer (score 0):

In your background job, make sure that the report is stored in the right folder. You can try something like:

```
report_target = Rails.root.join('public/my_report.xls')
report = ...
File.open(report_target, 'wb') { |file| file << report.generate }
```

Comment: I can store reports in tmp folder , and now i need to show latest 10 reports to download , how to fetch latest 10 reports?